# Firebase rule make sha1

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any option for create sha1 key and check it from new data

for example we are storing sha1() password and when login we will compare the result

Comment: Firebase stores the passwords for you. Additionally, they already salt and hash the passwords. If you want to hash passwords I don't recommend using SHA1. All you'd have to do is hash the password on the user end and upload the result. It's also important that you use a salt. No idea why you'd want to do any of this when Firebase handles this.

Comment: that should be posted as the answer of the question ^

Comment: with out login we are trying to saving some value and i need to make sure that data came from my android app, so i found a solution that use a key and i thing make sha1 for that key and from server check key is valid by makeing sha1 from my private key. for example i make sha1 code for my filed +"some key" then i recheck it from firebase rule.it is only possible if firebase rule have this option

Comment: You can't do this with security rules directly (there is no hashing available in the rules language) but you could write a Cloud Function to read the data in a temporary area, do the hash check, and then write it to the correct area if it matches.